# Sublime Text 2 not using new icon in Cmd-Tab on OS X

Tags: macos, sublime-text-2

I had previously exchanged the default icon for a custom icon. Upgrading to the latest update, which included a new, official icon, did not change the icon used when I change between programs (Cmd-Tab) or in the Dock. 
I have...

- checked if the update overwrote the custom icon and it did.
- restarted the computer.
- removed the .app and installed again.

Not sure what to try next.

Comment: Is the icon in the Dock correct?

Comment: @slhck No, the dock icon is also the old, custom icon. Forgot to add that to the question.

Comment: Try dragging the app from the dock, then pulling it back in. Could also try `killall Dock` from a Terminal then.

Comment: @slhck After I reinstalled Sublime, opened it, closed it and then opened it again, the correct, new icon showed up. So now it seems to be fixed.

Comment: Interesting -- probably best if you put that as an answer yourself!

Comment: It's called caching.

Comment: @DanielBeck Yeah, I figured as much but I had no idea __how__ to "fix" it.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me: reinstall Sublime Text 2, open, close and open again. Then the correct, new icon should show up.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem, I did the following:

1. Open Applications folder
2. Right click Sublime Text app and click "Get Info"
3. Open another finder window to the location of the `.icns` file you would like to use as replacement
4. Drag the new `.icns` file over the default icon in the **top left** of the open "Get Info" window

...this should do it! Worked for me anyway, no reinstallation necessary